# Interface not found when installing "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master"

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I am hoping someone can help me. Im using symfony 2.1 and have decided to try and use the bootstrap bundle from http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/.

I have added  "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master" into the require section of my composer file and have run `composer update`, but I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Interface 'Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\VoterInterface' not found in /home/ian/Zend/workspaces/DefaultWorkspace7/newmdr/vendor/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle/Braincrafted/BootstrapBundle/Voter/RequestVoter.php on line 20`

Anyone got an idea as to what the issue is? I'm going to hazard a guess at a dependency issue. Has anyone got a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
"knplabs/knp-menu": "dev-master"
```

to your `composer.json` in your symfony project folder. It'll install the menu that it needs.